# Displaying text when hovering over first list item in a un ordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have a li inside a ul and some hidden text on a page, how can I show that text when the user hovers over the first li in the ul?

I don't care if this is in CSS or JS, the text just has to appear only when hovering on the first itel in the list and no others. So when I hover over coffee, "hidden text" is visible

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<label style="display: none">hidden text</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with plain javascript:

```js
var first = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
var label = document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0];

first.onmouseover = function(){
   label.style.display = 'block';
}

first.onmouseout = function(){
   label.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<label style="display: none">hidden text</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `:first` selector or `first()` filter to locate the 1st element in a collection of elements.

```
$('ul li:first').hover(function()
{
  $('label').show();
}, function()
{
$('label').hide();
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/g6Lo4835/

```
$('ul li').first().hover(function()
{
  $('label').show();
},function()
{
  $('label').hide();
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/g6Lo4835/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $ul_menu = $('ul');

  $ul_menu.on('mouseover', function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName === 'LI'){
      if($(e.target).index() === 0){
        $('label').css('display', 'initial');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

JSFiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/51ekL5fg/3/).

I just simply added an event listener to the ul element, and checked the index of the li element, if it was 0, then it would update the css and show the hidden text.

**UPDATED**

```
  $ul_menu.on('mouseout', function(e){
     if(e.target && e.target.nodeName === 'LI'){
        if($(e.target).index() === 0){
        $label.css('display', 'none');
      }
    }
  });
```

You can add this to update the display to none on mouseout, and it will only modify it if it is the first li element.